# Deserializing DateOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this record that I'm trying to deserialize:

```cs
public record MementoTimeEntry
(
    Guid Id,
    Guid ActivityId,
    string UserId,
    string Title,
    TimeOnly StartTime,
    TimeOnly FinishTime,
    DateOnly Start,
    DateOnly ActivityDate,
    int Hours
);
```

However, I get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported.
```

Which is thankfully pretty clear what the issue is.

So, I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70104598/4700841) and [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539). However, neither seem to provide the full answer. Both make reference to a `DateOnlyConverter` but I can't seem to find this anywhere in the framework.

I've previously used the `[JsonPropertyConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]` attribute to achieve similar things.

So my question really boils down to:

Is this `DateOnlyConverter` something that already exists, or am I going to have to implement it myself?

If the answer is the latter, I'll do it and then post it as an answer to this question for future readers.

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace of that `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` converters will be released with [.NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539#issuecomment-1127634234).

For now you can create a custom one looking something like this (for `System.Text.Json`, for `Json.NET` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71021730/2501279) answer):

```cs
public class DateOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateOnly>
{
    private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public override DateOnly Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateOnly.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateOnly value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

And one of the possible usages would be:

```
class DateOnlyHolder
{
    // or via attribute [JsonConverter(typeof(DateOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public DateOnly dt { get; set; }
}

var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new DateOnlyJsonConverter() }
};
    
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new DateOnlyHolder{dt = new DateOnly(2022,1,2)}, jsonSerializerOptions);
Console.WriteLine(serialized); // prints {"dt":"2022-01-02"}
var de = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateOnlyHolder>(serialized, jsonSerializerOptions);
Console.WriteLine(de.dt); // prints 1/2/2022
```